# Getting a section to not appear in beamer tables of contents

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

How do I do that?  How would I get this one section frame to not appear?

```
\section{Section}
\subsection{}
\frame{
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `\section*{}` instead of `\section{}`. That works for me all of the time!

Comment: That makes complete sense.

Comment: This doesn't work for the section navigation that gets inserted into the headline by some templates.

Comment: I think this could be improved by mentioning that the same also applies  to `\chapter`, `part`, `\subsection` etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\section*{}` instead of `\section{}` instead of section. But this will require that you compile your file twice. Not a big deal but worth mentioning.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Compiling twice always applies for any change to the ToC.

Comment: This is already covered by the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are almost at the end of your presentation and you just want the last slides to disappear from the TOC, you can use `\appendix` before your section begins:

```
\appendix
\section{Section}
```

Comment: This is a wrong solution.  This would also make all subsequent sections not appear.  The correct solution is `\section*`.

Comment: Yes, this is right. I thought, I already pointed that out with my short explanation.

Comment: I know that this doesn't answer the initial question but it answered the question I had, which is why I gave it an upvote. Thank you. :)